# Export to pdf first and thrid page of the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, export

My problem is following:
I have a report, which I have to make, save and export to PDF everyday. So, lately I have found and incorporated macro to save first two pages and send it by outlook to chosen people. Now I want to upgrade this file, so I will need to export to PDF first and third page only. Here is sample of the code responsible for a export:

```
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False, From:=1, To:=2
  End With
```

How should remake this line?

Comment: Do you want exporting both sheets in the same pdf file, or to export two separate pdf files?

Comment: Let say I have workshhet "Report". I divided view of this sheet into page layout. And from this sheet i want to export 1st and 3rd page

Comment: OK. So, you need exporting the mentioned pages of the sheet in the same pdf file. Are there any shape involved? Especially in the second page, which must be skipped?

Comment: Right now I want to skip 2nd page, but in the future (maybe on July) I will print all 3 pages. My first page has table, and third have graphs. In the future there will be enough data to report on 3 pages ( tables + 1 graphs) . Currently I want to skip 2nd page, but I want it to be blank, becuase I want to make macros, which won't be changed in the future.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get you... What do you mean by " I want to skip 2nd page, but I want it to be blank, becuase I want to make macros, which won't be changed in the future"? Do you want skipping the second page, but still existing being blank? If yes, why the received answer should be inconvenient? I was asking about shapes (on the second page) involved, because, in such a situation, according to their properties, they may be moved on the third page.

Comment: I have a macros which are related to specific cells. Right nowy my report takes 2 pages (one for table, one for graphs). But in the future my report will take 3 pages (2 for tables, 1 for graphs). Below these 3 pages I have some calculus and other things which are used to make the report. So I want right now to make second page blank and skipped, because when there will be enough data to place on 3 pages, then no one will have to modify anything, simply the table will spread itself on 2nd page. I care about It, because I won't be doin this report in future, and my successor isnt familiar w vba

Comment: So basically. I want to have: FIrst page filled with data, second page blank, third page filled with graphs, and I want to export 1st  and 3rd page to one pdf file.

Comment: The way you put the problem is not related to your VBA skills, no offence... It is only related with the logic. Did you try the supplied code answer? It should do exactly what you describe about your need. If you tested it, what does it do against what you need? If not tested it, why that? I am repeating myself: The supplied code could have problems only if the second page contains shapes...

Comment: I know that I have a lot to learn in the future. I didn't answer because I was not in work so I Couldn't test it. However i wanted to get more options to maybe learn something new. Thanks for your assistance in this topic. I really appreciate your attention.

Comment: I think that he answer you received is the best, if there are there no shapes on the page to be skipped. In such a case, a better solution should be to copy the page, delete all the shapes from that page, delete the rows, export and delete the newly created sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can specify only a from and a to-page for the `ExportAsFixedFormat`-method. Passing 1 and 3, the PDF would contain also page 2.

However, the command will not include hidden rows, so all you have to do is to hide the rows temporarily before exporting. Drawback: If you are printing page numbers on the page header of footer, the page 3 will become page 2.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim page2 As Range

    If .HPageBreaks.Count >= 2 Then
        Set page2 = .Range(.HPageBreaks(1).Location,  .HPageBreaks(2).Location.Offset(-1, 0))
        page2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _ 
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False, From:=1, To:=2

    If Not page2 Is Nothing Then page2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It worked pretty well! Sorry for a long late response, but today I had opportunity to test it :)